# github action extract string from github.event.comment.body

Tags: github-actions

In GitHub action workflow, is there any way I can use split or similar process to extract a specific section from a comments? As an example I want to extract anything after "this is" from the whole body that reads "this is awesome! Have a good day!", to get only the string "awesome! Have a good day!" for further processing?

Tried below but seems not working as expected. Can someone please help?

```
steps:
      - run: echo ${{ github.event.comment.body.split('is')[-1] }}
      - name: Split branch name
        env:
          BODY: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
        id: split
        run: echo "::set-output name=fragment::${BODY##*/}"
```

Comment: Can you please check if my answer solves your issue? If yes, kindly accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [action-regex-match](https://github.com/actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match) action in your GitHub Actions workflow like:

```
steps:
  - name: Get PR comment
    uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
    id: get-pr-comment
    with:
      text: ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
      regex: '^(this is)(.*)$'
  - name: Echo extracted title
    run: |
      echo "${{ steps.get-pr-comment.outputs.group2 }}"
```

In the first step, the regex shall match two groups:

1. `this is` (`group1`)
2. Anything that comes after that (`group2`)

All groups are exposed as outputs of this step. Since we are looking for group2, that's what we shall use.

So in the second step, we shall retrieve this output by `${{ steps.get-pr-comment.outputs.group2 }}`.

Works fine in the test workflow I had created.

[image]